# How do I validate a string to only use numbers and output a message saying it has to be only numbers on Bluej

Tags: java, regex

I need to make the code below validate a string to only use numbers. I did an If statement but any time I run the program it outputs a message saying that the string cannot be integers.

Here are the variables:

```
private String personalIdNo;

private boolean isValidPersonalIdNo;
```

Here is the code I am having problems with, it won't work it always outputs "not integer" even if I put it as all numbers.

```
public void personalIdValidator()
{

    if (personalIdNo.matches("[0-9]"))
    {
        //Return True
    }
    else{
        isValidPersonalIdNo = false;
        System.out.println("The input is not only int");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check is almost correct, you just need to replace `personalIdNo.matches("[0-9]")` with either `personalIdNo.matches("[0-9]+")` or `personalIdNo.matches("[0-9]*")`, depending on whether you want the empty string to be valid as well.

Explanation:

Your current pattern means "one single character between `0` and `9`". Literally "one single character", so e.g. "1" or "4" would be valid inputs even with your code.
To allow for more than one character, there are two options:

1. `+` means "one or more characters"
2. `*` means "zero or more characters" (i.e. allowing the empty string as well)
3. (technically you could also specify a concrete number with `{min,max}`, but I don't think that's what you want)

Note that this pattern currently also prevents negative numbers. If you want to also allow negative numbers, you could use `personalIdNo.matches("-?[0-9]+")`, where `?` means "zero or one occurrences".

Proof/Code sample:

```
public class NumberTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        personalIdValidator("");
        personalIdValidator("0");
        personalIdValidator("1");
        personalIdValidator("123");
        personalIdValidator("-123");
        personalIdValidator("--123");
        personalIdValidator("abc");
        personalIdValidator("1a2b3c");
        personalIdValidator("‎٤‎٥‎٦‎٧‎٨‎");
    }

    public static void personalIdValidator(String personalIdNo) {
        if (personalIdNo.matches("-?[0-9]+")) {
            System.out.println("The input is only int");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The input is not only int");
        }
    }
}

// The input is not only int
// The input is only int
// The input is only int
// The input is only int
// The input is only int
// The input is not only int
// The input is not only int
// The input is not only int
// The input is not only int
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\\d` - any digit.

Comment: @JockX: True, although IMHO this is merely a matter of taste in Java (unlike maybe some other languages where `\d` might include non-arabic numerals as well).